# How can I set the DataBinding to an arbitrary Property in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have the following problem: I am designing an UserControl, a graded-color gauge. I have decieded to use the MVVM design patern, which turns out to be a good choice. However, I have the following problem. In the View XAML file, I try to convert a value to a color, using custtom converter, which needs 2 parameters. For this purpose, I use the MultiBinding:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Height="2">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource colorConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Value"/>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Palette_ICOS}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The thing is, that I don't want to use

> {StaticResource Palette_ISO1}

as a second parameter, but a Property, which is a direct property of the DataContext and is not a property of the ViewData collection member. I have tried several ways to accomplish this scenario, but without signifficant success.

As last, I have tried the following:

```
<Binding Path="CurrentPallete"/>
```

and the CurrentPallete looks like:

```
public Palette CurrentPalette
{
    get { return _currentPalette; }
    set
    {
        _currentPalette = value;
    }
 }
```

i.e. a Property in the Class, whose instance is set as a DataContext of the **main** control, which hosts the **ItemControl**. What I get is a

```
[0x00000001] = {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
```

value in the Debugger, when the corresponding convertor is invoked,which probably means, that the Property cannot be found. Can anyone point out what is the way to achieve the desired effect? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
<Binding Path="DataContext.Palette_ICOS"
         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}" />
```

Comment: I think you meant `Path` there, also some words of explanaition wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Correct, that is the solution I needed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<Binding Path="Palette_ICOS"/>
```

If `Palette_ICOS` is a property in the current item's `DataContext` binding it should work.